# why JQuery Mobile not able to check the checkbox?

Tags: checkbox, jquery-mobile

I put a checkbox on my webpage, but I want to check it, base on the content of the text file.
I am using the below code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
    
          $.ajax({
        url : "CH1.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
            $("CH1.text").html(data);
            
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(data);
            
            
            if(data=="1"){$("#CH1CheckBox").prob('checked', true);
                else $("#CH1CheckBox").prob('checked', false);
        
            
        }
    });
       });
```

when I remove the below script that belonged to JQuery mobile, everything is ok.

but when I use the JQM it not works.
I already test with the .attr() function as well, but not constructive.
please help.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should [read the documentation](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0.1/docs/forms/checkboxes/methods.html). You need to refresh the element afterwards..

This is how you set the check box:

```
$("#CH1CheckBox").prop('checked',true).checkboxradio('refresh');
```

To clear the check box:

```
$("#CH1CheckBox").prop('checked',false).checkboxradio('refresh');
```